# Automatic column number and width adjustment

Tags: beamer, multicol

I have a body of text formatted into columns that I frequently edit. When I add text to the first column, the appearance of the columns is unbalanced and I have to manually cut/paste text over to the next column to improve the aesthetic. Can I automate this somehow? I do not want to have to specify the number (and width) of the columns. I want the compiler to work out the best (most even) distribution of words between the columns based on the text that I have entered. Below is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[gray]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Product Concept}
\begin{columns}[t]
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\small
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\small
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
\end{column}
\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\small
into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike a normal document a presentation normally requires manual control over column and page breaking however you can use `multicols` if you wish:

[image]

```
\documentclass[gray]{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Product Concept}
\begin{multicols}{3}

\small
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 

1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap

into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
\end{multicols}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sitting here with a big smile on my face, thanks to you and your solution.